# Joining SQL tables on the column that has a value

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have the following tables

```
Collection DirectorId StudioId
   1             NULL      1
   2             2         NULL
   3             NULL      2


Director MovieId
  1        1
  2        4

Studio   MovieId
  1        1
  2        3
  2        4
  1        2
```

The collection table will always have either director or studio id but never both.

How could I write a query to get all the movies in one a collection so that I end up with

```
CollectionID MovieID
1            1
1            2
2            4
3            3
3            4
```

I hope this makes sense

Comment: I'm a database amateur, but I would point out that first table doesn't seem to be normalized. You have two fields, where really one boolean field would make more sense (since it's an XOR type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (not sure about your column names, but you get the idea):

```
select c.CollectionID, isnull(d.MovieId, s.MovieId) MovieID
from Collection c
left join Director d on d.Director=c.DirectorId
left join Studio s on s.Studio=c.StudioId
```